# Configuring JMeter for Sequential Thread Execution with Parallel Load Testing

Tags: multithreading, testing, groovy, jmeter, load-testing

I'm currently working on a JMeter test plan that involves three thread groups. Typically, I run them one by one, ensuring sequential execution by checking the "Run Thread Groups consecutively" checkbox.

However, I now find myself facing a challenge in configuring the test plan to meet the following criteria:

```
1.Execute the first thread group once.
2.Execute the second thread group simultaneously for 500 users for a load test.
3.Execute the third thread group once.
```

*Here's the catch: the threads are dependent on each other, meaning they should run sequentially. Additionally, when the second thread group is in execution, it should run concurrently for 500 users only after the completion of the first thread group.*

I'm looking for guidance on how to set up JMeter to achieve this specific sequence and parallelism. Any insights, suggestions, or step-by-step instructions would be immensely helpful. Thanks a lot!

"I've set up a test plan with three threads, running sequentially. While this works well, I'm facing a challenge with the second thread. I need to perform a load test with 500 users, but when I use a Loop Controller for the second thread, it executes users one by one. Instead, I want all 500 users to run concurrently. How can I achieve this?"

[Here is my 2nd thread group which i want to execute for 500 users concurrently after 1st thread group is executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZVaT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - it executes users according to your [Ramp-Up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period), number of iterations and/or the time to hold the load.

- JMeter starts threads according to ramp-up time, if its 0 or 1 - JMeter will start all 500 users at the same moment
- Once started each user will begin executing Samplers upside down (or according to the Logic Controllers)
- When last Sampler is executed - next iteration begins
- When there are no more samplers to execute and no more loops to iterate - the thread finishes
- When there are no more running threads - the test finishes

You can either share your configuration or amend it according to the above information or consider switching to i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides easy visual way of defining ramp-up, time to hold the load, ramp-down, spikes, whatever you want.

Comment: I checked the checkbox "Run threads consecutively" to execute the thread groups one by one. Consequently, the second thread group is not concurrently executing the HTTP requests for all 500 users; instead, it is executing them one by one.

Comment: It's your Thread Group settings, if you show your setup I'll tell you what it means, if you tell me what you want to achieve - I'll give you the setup. If you want to run 500 requests once at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer). If you want to see the concurrency - check [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/). The latter one can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: hi , i have added my setup photo... please help me out !

Comment: This is CSV Data Set Config and I was asking for the Thread Group with the desired workload model pattern.